# Probability of $0\leq X\leq Y$ for two standard Gaussian random variables random variables

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, normal-distribution

We are given two independent standard Gaussian random variables $X\sim N(0, \sigma_x^2), Y\sim N(0, \sigma_y^2)$. Compute $Pr(X-Y\leq 0 \cap X\geq 0)$.

Here is what I did so far:

Denote by $\mathbb{1}(x)$ a function which is $1$ if $0\leq x \leq y$ and $0$ else. Moreover let $F(x)$ be th CDF of $X$ and $G(y)$ the CDF of $Y$.

$Pr(X-Y \leq 0 \cap X\geq 0)=Pr(0\leq X \leq Y)=\int \int \mathbb{1}(x) dF(x)dG(y)=\int \int_0^y F'(x) dx dG(y)=\int \frac{1}{2} erf(\frac{y}{\sqrt{2\sigma_x^2}})dG(y)  $ But now I don't know which bound do apply to the integral? $0$ to $\infty?$

EDIT: Please note that $X$ and $Y$ have different variances.

Comment: you cannot compute anything  if you do not have further information about the dependence stucture between $X$ and $Y$

Comment: They are independent

Comment: @tommik why did you delete you answer? Btw I deleted too based on a question OP asked :)

Comment: @MathLover : I assumed standard gaussians or centered gaussian with same variance...in OP question the variances are different...I'm not sure my solution is right. I think you can check it

Comment: @tommik exactly the reason I deleted too. Once OP asked a question, I noticed they wrote $\sigma_x^2$ and $\sigma_y^2$.

Comment: To OP, please check if both are $N~(0,\sigma^2)$ or not. Are variances really different? Once you clarify, I can reinstate my answer.

Comment: Hello, yes it are truly two different variances

Comment: using @MathLover answer, simply changing the variables (rescaling) I think the solution easy follows

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Can you please reinstate your answers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As $X$ and $Y$ are independent,

$ \displaystyle f(x,y) = \frac{1}{2 \pi \sigma_x \sigma_y} \ e^{- \left(\dfrac{x^2}{2\sigma_x^2} + \dfrac{y^2}{2\sigma_y^2}\right)}$

$X - Y \leq 0 \cap X \geq 0 \implies 0 \leq X \leq Y$,

Use change of variable,

$x = r \sqrt{2} \ \sigma_x \cos\theta, y = r \sqrt{2} \ \sigma_y \sin\theta$

Jacobian $|J| = 2  r  \sigma_x  \sigma_y$

$Y \geq X \geq 0 \implies \dfrac{\sigma_x}{\sigma_y} \leq \tan \theta$.

So, $ \ \arctan \left(\dfrac{\sigma_x}{\sigma_y}\right) \leq \theta \leq \dfrac{\pi}{2}$.

$0 \leq r \leq \infty$

$ \displaystyle P(0 \leq X \leq Y) = \int_{\arctan(\sigma_x / \sigma_y)}^{\pi/2} \int_0^{\infty} |J| \ f(r,\theta) \ dr \ d\theta$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your answer. What is $\sigma$?

Comment: Standard deviation $\sigma$ assuming it is standard gaussian $N~(0,1)$

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your answer. How did you derive at $f(x,y)$ this is simply the convolution? $f(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{infty} f_X(t-z)f_y(z)dt?$

Comment: For independent random variables $X, Y$, $f(x,y) = f(x) f(y)$

Comment: Ah thanks! I forgot that

Comment: Is r by definition $0\leq r \leq \infty$?

Comment: Yes as upper bounds of $X, Y$ are $\infty$, upper bound of $r$ is $\infty$ (given $\cos$ and $\sin$ are bound between $0$ and $1$ in first quadrant.

Comment: I am still fighting with your bounds on $r$ and $\Theta$. If we set $0\leq r \leq \Theta$ then from $Y\geq X$ follows $\frac{\sigma_x}{\sigma_y} \leq \tan(\Theta)$ and since $0\leq X$ we obtain$-\frac{\pi}{2}\leq \Theta\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$ and from $Y\geq 0$ we obtain $0 \leq \Theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$, but then we only have $0\leq \Theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126990/discussion-between-math-lover-and-samabu).

Answer (score 0):

As a hint towards the solution:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your contribution. So I think, I have to interpret your hint as follows. The green area is the one we are interested in, because then $X\geq 0$ and $Y\geq X$. Why are you considering an ellipse? And I think I still have to calculate things explicitely, because the variance is different, we should not be able to simply see the solution by drawing something. Right?

Comment: samabu I have added a second, rescaled, picture with @tommik's suggestion.  A bivariate normal distribution has elliptical lines of equal density

Comment: Ok, so I see the solution is $1/8$, but I still don't get exactly why

Comment: @samabu The answer is only $\frac18$ if the two variances are equal